# How to exclude a specific file in find

Tags: linux, shell, find

Suppose my directory structure looks like

```
A--file1.cpp
   file2.cpp
   file3.cpp
   file1.h
   file2.h
   file3.h

B--file1.cpp
   file2.cpp
   file3.cpp
   file1.h
   file2.h
   file3.h
```

and my goal is to find every cpp file besides `file1.cpp` in the A folder

`find A/ B/ -name \*.cpp` will find all the files, and I tried `find A/ B/ ! -name file1.cpp -name \*.cpp` this will exclude `file1.cpp` from the B folder as well. `find A/ B/ -prune -o file1.cpp -name \*.cpp` doesn't work either. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-path` predicate will let you ignore a specific file or directory.

```
find . -path ./A/file1.cpp -prune -o -type f -name '*.cpp' -print
```

Tested as follows:

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d "$TMPDIR"/test.d.XXXXXX)
cd "$tempdir" && {
  mkdir -p A B
  touch {A,B}/file{1,2,3}.{cpp,h}
  find A B -path A/file1.cpp -prune -o -type f -name '*.cpp' -print
  rm -rf -- "$tempdir"
}
```

...emitting output of:

```
A/file2.cpp
A/file3.cpp
B/file1.cpp
B/file2.cpp
B/file3.cpp
```

Comment: I tried `find A/ B/ -path ./A/file1.cpp -prune -o -type f -print` and it's showing all 6 files

Comment: I've amended with test procedure and output. You can copy-and-paste that yourself.

Comment: Your `-path` predicate needs to write the name in accordance with the `path` argument you passed to `find` telling it where/how to start the search. Thus, if you pass `find` the directory name `A`, it's `A/file1.cpp`.

Comment: It works, but I have `.h` files in the folder as well, so my problem might be too simplified, let me edit it and I will appreciate an updated answer

Comment: Amended appropriately.

Comment: `find A/ B/ -path A/file1.cpp -prune -o -type f -print` will include the `.h` files, I suppose I can add in something like `*.h` to the prune list as well, but in the actual folder there are `.xml`, `.cmake` files with all sorts of extensions, listing them exhaustively may not be the best way, please advice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136801/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-user3667089).

Comment: Even simpler, you can avoid using `-prune` as such: `find . \! -path ./A/file1.cpp -iname "*.cpp" -type f` (note it's faster to test for type after testing for name since this avoids calling `stat` on every file)